# Series Resistance-Capacitance Circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, ac, reactance

I have an optocoupler and I connect it to 230V, the datasheet tell me the optocoupler has a forward voltage: IF = ± 5 mA VF - 1.5 V, so, for limiting the current I need an resistor of 4.7K - 11wats, but I don't have this type of resistor so I use a Capacitor and a Resistor in series, but my problem is that I don't know how to calculate the value of the capacitor resistance (Xc=?), and if i know the capacitor value, what value resistor should have?

[image]

Comment: For Xc: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_reactance#Capacitive_reactance ?

Answer (score 2):

The reactance of the capacitor \$C\$ is (magnitude):
$$X_c = \frac{1} {Cw} $$
Where \$w = 2\pi f_{Line} \$

Net series impedance is therefore:
$$ |Z|= \sqrt{R^2+X_c^2} $$